# Not able to add new address field in RecyclerView When "Add More Address" button is clicked?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a form that has a recyclerView for address and above the RecyclerView there is a Button which onClick able to add more address fields inside this RecyclerView but not able to do that instead when the button has clicked the app crashed.
Here is the Log output I got

Process: com.fitness.client, PID: 10162[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY0wr.jpg)

*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
        at* androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.removeAndRecycleAllViews(RecyclerView.java:10079)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.removeAndRecycleViews(RecyclerView.java:1174)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapterInternal(RecyclerView.java:1197)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(RecyclerView.java:1156)
        at com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.listing.ListingFragment$1.onClick(ListingFragment.java:144)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)

And here is the code of my fragment

AND btw the BUTTON name is "address"

```
package com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.listing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.fitness.client.BR;
import com.fitness.client.R;
import com.fitness.client.api.RetroFitFactory;
import com.fitness.client.api.product.ProductDetailResponse;
import com.fitness.client.api.user.UserProfileResponse;
import com.fitness.client.api.user.UserService;
import com.fitness.client.base.classes.BaseFragment;
import com.fitness.client.base.classes.BaseRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.fitness.client.base.classes.BaseViewHolder;
import com.fitness.client.databinding.ItemOfferingBinding;
import com.fitness.client.databinding.ItemProductListingBinding;
import com.fitness.client.objects.Product;
import com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.listing.adapter.AddressAdapter;
import com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.listing.adapter.DescriptionAdapter;
import com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.listing.adapter.EmailAdapter;
import com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.listing.adapter.FacilitesAdapter;
import com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.listing.adapter.PhoneAdapter;
import com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.listing.adapter.TagAdapter;
import com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.listing.adapter.TermsAdapter;
import com.fitness.client.ui.main.fragments.listing.adapter.TimingAdapter;
import com.fitness.client.ui.offering.OfferingActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ListingFragment extends BaseFragment<ItemProductListingBinding, ListingViewModel, ListingNavigator> implements ListingNavigator {

    public String TAG = "ListingFragment";
    private AddressAdapter addressAdapter;
    private EmailAdapter emailAdapter;
    private FacilitesAdapter facilitesAdapter;
    private PhoneAdapter phoneAdapter;
    private DescriptionAdapter descriptionAdapter;
    private TermsAdapter termsAdapter;
    private TagAdapter tagAdapter;
    private TimingAdapter timingAdapter;

    private OfferingAdapter offeringAdapter;
    private LinearLayout addressLayout;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    private int ids = 0;
    private int hint = 0;

    public static ListingFragment getInstance(Context context) {
        return (ListingFragment) ListingFragment.instantiate(context, ListingFragment.class.getName());
    }


    @Override
    public int getBindingVariable() {
        return BR.listing_view_model;

    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.item_product_listing;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(View view, Bundle savedInstances) {
        addressAdapter = new AddressAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
        emailAdapter = new EmailAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
        facilitesAdapter = new FacilitesAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
        phoneAdapter = new PhoneAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
        descriptionAdapter = new DescriptionAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
        termsAdapter = new TermsAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
        tagAdapter = new TagAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
        timingAdapter = new TimingAdapter(new ArrayList<>());

        offeringAdapter = new OfferingAdapter(new ArrayList<>());


        getViewDataBinding().addressList.setAdapter(addressAdapter);
        getViewDataBinding().emailList.setAdapter(emailAdapter);
        getViewDataBinding().facilitiesList.setAdapter(facilitesAdapter);
        getViewDataBinding().phoneList.setAdapter(phoneAdapter);
        getViewDataBinding().descriptionList.setAdapter(descriptionAdapter);
        getViewDataBinding().termsAndConditionsList.setAdapter(termsAdapter);
        getViewDataBinding().tagList.setAdapter(tagAdapter);
        getViewDataBinding().timingList.setAdapter(timingAdapter);
        getViewDataBinding().offeringList.setAdapter(offeringAdapter);


        getViewModel().requestData();

//        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
//                Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
       View view1 = inflater != null ? inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_edit_box, null) : null;


//        addressLayout =getViewDataBinding().layoutmain;
        if (view != null) {
            addressLayout = view1 != null ? view1.findViewById(R.id.createLayout) : null;
        }
        Log.e("Listing Fragment", String.format("Recyler View LAYOUT %s", addressLayout));
//        addressLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.createLayout);
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        final int[] i = {0};
        getViewDataBinding().address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i[0] = i[0] + 1;
//                TextView more = new TextView(getContext());
//                more.setText(String.format("Address %s", i[0]));
//                more.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
//                more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ids++;
                hint++;
                EditText newEdit = new EditText(getContext());
                newEdit.setHint(String.format("Address %s", hint));
                newEdit.setId(ids);
                newEdit.setMinLines(4);

                Log.e("New Edittext: ", String.valueOf(ids));
                newEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
//                addressLayout.addView(more);
                addressLayout.addView(newEdit,layoutParams);
                getViewDataBinding().addressList.addView(addressLayout);
                AddressAdapter addressAdapter1 = new AddressAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
//                getViewDataBinding().addressList.addView(addressLayout);
                getViewDataBinding().addressList.setAdapter(addressAdapter1);
                addressAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                 getViewDataBinding().moreAddress.setAdapter(addressAdapter);
//               addressAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


//                ListingFragment fragment = (ListingFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
//                if (fragment != null) {
//                    fragment.addressAdapter.getAdapter().newAddeddata();
//                }

                //                getViewDataBinding().
//                getViewDataBinding().moreAddress.setAdapter(addressAdapter);
//                addressAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(getContext());
//               recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
//               recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
//               recyclerView.setAdapter(addressAdapter);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void updateProductList(List<Product> products) {

        if (products != null && products.size() > 0) {
            for (Product product : products) {
                getViewModel().requestProductDetails(product.getId());
            }

        } else {
            showToast("No products found");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setUpProductDetails(ProductDetailResponse data) {

        offeringAdapter.addData(data.getData().getOffer_package());


    }

    @Override
    public void setProfileInformation(UserProfileResponse body) {
        getViewDataBinding().name.setText(body.getData().getName());
        timingAdapter.addData(body.getData().getTiming_info());
        termsAdapter.addData(Collections.singletonList(body.getData().getMerchant_info().getTermscondition()));

        Log.e("Listing Fragment", "Terms: " + Collections.singletonList(body.getData().getMerchant_info().getTermscondition()));

        tagAdapter.addData(Collections.singletonList(body.getData().getMerchant_info().getBusiness_tags()));
        descriptionAdapter.addData(Collections.singletonList(body.getData().getMerchant_info().getDescription()));
        addressAdapter.addData(body.getData().getAddress());
        if (body.getData().getFacilities_info().getFacilities() != null)
            facilitesAdapter.addData(Arrays.asList(body.getData().getFacilities_info().getFacilities().split(",")));
        List<String> emailList = Arrays.asList(body.getData().getContact_info().getAlter_email_1(),
                body.getData().getContact_info().getAlter_email_2(),
                body.getData().getContact_info().getAlter_email_3(),
                body.getData().getContact_info().getAlter_email_4());
//        emailAdapter.addData(emailList);
        emailAdapter.addData(emailList);
        Log.e("Listing Fragment", "Email: " + emailList);


//        phoneAdapter.addData(body.getData().getContact_info());

        List<String> phoneList = Arrays.asList(body.getData().getContact_info().getAlter_mobile_1(),
                body.getData().getContact_info().getAlter_mobile_2(),
                body.getData().getContact_info().getAlter_mobile_3(),
                body.getData().getContact_info().getAlter_mobile_4());
        Log.e("Listing Fragment", "Phone Number: " + phoneList);
        phoneAdapter.addData(phoneList);
//        phoneAdapter.addData(Arrays.asList(body.getData().getContact_info().getAlter_mobile_1(),
//                );


        getViewDataBinding().update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showLoading("Loading", "Please wait while update your profile");

                RetroFitFactory.getRetrofitCallFor(UserService.class)
                        .updateUserProfile();

            }
        });
    }


    class OfferingAdapter extends BaseRecyclerViewAdapter<OfferingAdapter.OfferingHolder, ProductDetailResponse.Offer_packageEntity> {

        public OfferingAdapter(List<ProductDetailResponse.Offer_packageEntity> data) {
            super(data);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public OfferingHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new OfferingHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_offering, parent, false));
        }

        class OfferingHolder extends BaseViewHolder<ProductDetailResponse.Offer_packageEntity, ItemOfferingBinding> {


            public OfferingHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

            }

            @Override
            protected void bindObject(ProductDetailResponse.Offer_packageEntity object) {
                getViewDataBinding().setOffering(object);

                getViewDataBinding().viewSch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), OfferingActivity.class);
                        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", object.getDays_timing());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
              /*   adapter.clear();
                ProductDetailResponse.Days_timingEntity placeHolder = new ProductDetailResponse.Days_timingEntity();
                placeHolder.setDay("Day");
                placeHolder.setWeek("Week");
                adapter.addData(Collections.singletonList(placeHolder));
                adapter.addData(object.getDays_timing());*/


            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create functions in your adapter, named addItem and removeItem

watch this video for a more detailed explanation
: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enTvZm9LOGc&t=247s